# Siblings move in with creepy uncle

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this movie when I was a boy and all I remember of it is that these two children brothers and sister have to move in with their creepy uncle in a mansion, and someone died after being eaten by a snake in a greenhouse and another may have died after eating then swimming and getting cramps. In the end of the movie the kids end up in the top of a bell tower where a play is taking place in a courtyard and the uncle may be trying to kill them. I know this may sound confusing but please help it's been on my mind for over a year.

Comment: when were you a boy? 70s 80s 90s??

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like [Lemony Snicket's A Series of Unfortunate Events](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0339291/combined) with Jim Carrey from 2004. It's about three orphans pursued by an evil relative named Count Olaf who's after their money.

[image]

Many things you've mentioned take place there: One aunt is presumably killed by leeches because she has cramps while swimming, another uncle is supposedly killed by a giant snake (but the snake was framed), and in the end, Count Olaf stages a play in order to marry his young relative, but his plan is foiled when [the marriage certificate is burned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZ0nnL_Fio4) by a magnifying glass on top of a tower. [Here's the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWB1HGnA3tA).

Comment: Wow - I thought is it really 20 years old?!?  No - it was from 2004.  A surprisingly underrated movie in my opinion.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that. Thanks for the correction

Comment: The outtake of Carrey doing a Tyrannasaurus impression is wet-your-pants hysterical.

Answer (score 0):

Lets kill uncle 1966
A 12-year-old orphan who has just inherited a fortune is trapped on an island with his uncle, a former British intelligence commander who intends to kill him. A young girl is the boy's only ally against the sarcastic uncle, who uses hypnotism, a pool of sharks, fire, and poisonous mushrooms as weapons.

Comment: Why are you submitting so many same answer, kindly give one answer only and use edit button to add additional information